Accessing Linux files with FACL
OS: Oracle Linux 9.4
I am getting a FACL permissions error on files in /var/www/html
[hussain@mybalancer ~]$ ls -l /var/www/html/index.html
ls: cannot access '/var/www/html/index.html': Permission denied
[hussain@mybalancer ~]$ sudo ls -l /var/www/html/index.html
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 hussain builddeployers 1029 Nov  7  2023 /var/www/html/index.html
[hussain@mybalancer ~]$ sudo getfacl /var/www/html/index.html
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/www/html/index.html
# owner: hussain
# group: builddeployers
user::rw-
group::rwx                      #effective:rw-
group:builddeployers:rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--

I had been working on the files in this directory since this machine was first installed and no one else logs on to it, so no idea how this ACL restriction came to be in place. Didn't know about access control lists, but from the output above, I should be able to access it as I am the owner of the file.
getenforce shows that SELinux is in disabled state.
How can I disable these FACL's that have been applied?

What access do you have to the html directory?

Please edit the output of namei -l /var/www/html/index.html into your question.

I managed to remove these using sudo setfacl -b -R /var/www/html/
